# Show that the iterated integral is a continuous function

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have got the following question:

> Let $f: R:= [a,b] \times [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous on $R$. 
> Let $G: [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $G(y) := \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx$.
> Show that G is continuous on [c,d].

My approach:

> It suffices to show that G is uniform continuous on [c,d].
> Let $\epsilon > 0$. Note that $\forall y_1, y_2 \in [c,d]$ ,
> $|G(y_1) - G(y_2)| = |\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_1) \,dx - \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_2) \,dx|
>                    = |\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2) \,dx|$.
> By Mean Value Theorem, $\exists k$ between $y_1, y_2$ such that $f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)(y_1 - y_2)$.
> Then $|G(y_1) - G(y_2)| = |\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)(y_1 - y_2) \,dx|$.
> Now $y_1 - y_2$ is just a constant with respect to $x$ and hence we can take it out to yield $|y_1 - y_2||\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)\,dx|$.
> Also, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)$ is a function of $x$. Let $F$ be the primitive function of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)$ i.e. $F'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)$.
> Then we have $|\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,k)\,dx| = |\int_{a}^{b} F'(x)\,dx| = |F(b) - F(a)|$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
> Hence $|G(y_1) - G(y_2)| = |y_1 - y_2||F(b) - F(a)|$.
> It remains to take $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{|F(b) - F(a)|}$ and the result follows.

Please comment on this approach. Is it correct or not?
If not, could anyone provide some hints on the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $F$ depends on $k$ and so does $|F(b)-F(a)$.

Correct argument: Just note that $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}$ is continuous on the compact set $R$, so $|\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(x,k)|$ has a  maximum $M$ on $R$. Now you  get $|G(y_1)-G(y_2)| \leq M|y_1-y_2|$.